# Fetch/TemplateLiteral issue passing Data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, template-literals

I'm building a weather app in react that pulls location and date data from the browser. Upon getting the location data, the app renders a header that tells you the season based on the lat and month, gives you a GoogleMap window of your pulled location, and fetches data from http://api.weatherapi.com/v1 to get a 5-day forecast. I'm specifically using prop-drilling for this project to show understanding of unidirectional data flow, so I'm trying to avoid using hooks for this particular app. I also have conditional rendering set in place for alerts.

Everything is Working!!!
My lat/lon is pulling correctly and saving in my state object, as is my initial fetch request of "Chicago" from the weather api for weatherForecast data. I have two components inside the App: a SeasonDisplay to show the season header, and a LocationData component that passes the necessary lat and lon coords down as props.
*** SeasonDisplay Works as Expected.

```
import React from "react";
import SeasonDisplay from './SeasonDisplay';
import './SeasonDisplay.css';
import Loader from './loader.js';
import LocationData from "./LocationData";
import "./App.css";
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            lat: null,
            lon: null,
            mapData: [],
            weatherForecast: [],
            errorMessage: null
        }
    }
    async componentDidMount() {
        await window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            (position) => {
                this.setState({ lat: position.coords.latitude });
                this.setState({ lon: position.coords.longitude });
            },
            (error) => this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message })
        );
        const response = await fetch(`http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=///apiKey///&q="Chicago"&days=5`)
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({ weatherForecast: data.forecast.forecastday });
    }
    renderContent() {
        if(this.state.errorMessage || !this.state.lat) {
            return <h2>Error: {this.state.errorMessage}</h2>;
        } else if (!this.state.errorMessage && this.state.lat) {
            return (
                    <div id="container">
                        <div>
                            <SeasonDisplay
                                lat={this.state.lat}
                                lon={this.state.lon}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div id="locationData">
                            <LocationData
                                lat={this.state.lat}
                                lon={this.state.lon}
                                weatherForecast={this.state.weatherForecast}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
            );
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <Loader message="Waiting on You..." />
            </div>
        )
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="container">
                {this.renderContent()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default App;
```

In my LocationData component, I take the lat/lon props and pass them to two other components, GoogleApiWrapper and WeatherCard.

*** GoogleApiWrapper Works as Expected, so I know I'm passing my props correctly to the LocationData Component, and that the state from App is passing data down, as opposed to null or undefined.

```
import React from "react";
import GoogleApiWrapper from "../APIs/mapsAPI";
import WeatherCard from "./WeatherCard";
import "./LocationData.css";
const LocationData = props => {
  return (
    <div className="locationData">
      <GoogleApiWrapper
        lat={props.lat}
        lon={props.lon}
      />
      <WeatherCard
        lat={props.lat}
        lon={props.lon}
        weatherForecast={props.weatherForecast}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
export default LocationData;
```

From here, the lat/lon props ARE passing to the WeatherCard component, which maps the weatherForecast index data to a card that renders next to the map. (fixing this before I change card flow). As a test to make sure the props are passing, I added lat and lon to weather card to I could see the data in ReactDevTools/Comonents, and the Lat/Lon data is there.

So everything is working.

****Heres the Problem****

I can't get the lat/lon state values to pass properly in the fetch request. I've tried several times using template literals, but the api doc is confusing. I was using axios earlier, but removed that because when trying to pass key/value params, i kept getting cities like Null in South America or Lat in norway.....

the documentation says to pass it as:

```
Latitude and Longitude (Decimal degree) e.g: q=48.8567,2.3508
```

So i've tried passing various versions of

```
const response = await fetch(`http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=///apiKey///&q=${this.props.lat},${this.props.lon}&days=5`)
```

to make it location specific to the end user, but it keeps passing returning results from Null in Ecuador...
So my lat value is passing in before the location data is set, though in ReactDevTools, both lat and long are showing up correctly.

How can I pass the lat/lon values to get my forecast data for the appropriate location???

Also, this is my first post, so bear with me while I try to follow formatting at risk of over-sharing...
Any Feedback would be Premium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting state is mostly async, so if you want to use newly set state values you'd look into doing that in the callback to setState. Also avoid multiple `setState` calls, you can combine them into one:

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    await window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;
        this.setState(
          {
            lat: latitude,
            lon: longitude,
          },
          async () => {
            // use calback here
            const response = await fetch(
              `http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=///apiKey///${this.state.lat},${this.state.lon}&days=5`
            );
            const data = await response.json();
            console.log(data);
            this.setState({
              weatherForecast: data.forecast.forecastday,
            });
          }
        );
      },
      error =>
        this.setState({
          errorMessage: error.message,
        })
    );
  }
```

Comment: ok, so i was doing it right, but i needed an embedded async/await statement to trigger the api call after I set the coords?

Comment: It works perfectly now!!! Thanks for the help!!!
Also, just to be a better dev, lmk if theres any changes you made that I miss:

Comment: destructure lat/lon;
move api call to inside coords request, ensuring I have the right coords set before passing that state on to the api call.

Comment: @KieranMilligan the issue was that when you were making the api call the values haven't been yet set on the state, so that's why you need to use callback to setState to ensure that's the case. Also remember to accept the answer if it solves your issue :)